# How to find one end of cat-5e cable hidden in a wall

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

I have a junction box in my house where seven cat 5E cables originate. The ends of the cables inside the junction box are all attached to a patch panel. I can only find four wall plates in the house where I can plug in Ethernet cables. I have no idea where the other 3 cables terminate. Is there a way to find where the other three cables terminate if they are hidden in the walls and not connected to a wall plate?

Comment: I'm not sure if this really fits with the purpose of this community. Perhaps asking in one more suited for questions such as this would yield better answers?

Comment: First thing I would do is look behind the faceplates and see if there are cables there.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use a tone generator such as this, you can use the tracer and drag it along walls to track the cable.

[image]

This one is from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CZDLB9S).

Comment: I was going to post an answer like this with the proviso that you will need a pretty sensitive tone generator and whether it will work depends on the wall construction.